# How to set up custom product sorting on WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce shop that was built with Genesis Framework and Jessica child theme.

When I check the default ordering options within the theme, there is no ability to select "Custom ordering". I assume that this option would enable end-users to take control on how products within a category are ordered.

After some research, I think I found the hook where this is handled, `woocommerce_catalog_orderby`, however I am not familiar with activating or enabling this feature.

*Screenshot with available sorting options*

[image: Available sorting options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting for sorting products in the catalog is correct.

From **Appearance** > **Customize** > **WooCommerce** > **Product Catalog** you have to set the value for the *Default product sorting* option in *Default sorting (custom ordering + name)* or **Standaard sorteervolgorde**.

> Now you need to set a value for the **`menu_order`** meta field of
> each product.
>
> You can enter any numeric value, even negative.

The product with the lowest `menu_order` will be shown first.

**Note:** The sorting applies to both the product catalog (shop page) and the product category pages.

Example:

```
position #1    Product A    menu_order -8
position #2    Product B    menu_order  1
position #3    Product C    menu_order  4
```

You can set the value of the `menu_order` field in **3 ways**.

#### METHOD #1

From the Wordpress admin page go to: **WooCommerce** > **Products**.
You will find the **Sorting** item next to the product statuses.
If you click on it you can drag and drop the products. The products above will be the first shown.

[image]

#### METHOD 2

You can change it within the product page in the Wordpress admin. Then go to **WooCommerce** > **Products**. Click the **Edit** button on the product you want to edit. Then go to the **Advanced** tab and set the value of **Menu order**.

[image]

#### METHOD #3

Finally you can set the value **by importing a .csv file** from the default WooCommerce import function.

Below you will find the WooCommerce documentation with the list of available product fields (including `menu_order`) and how to import them via .csv file: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/